# Meteor Js , Store images to mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, gridfs, meteorite

I want to store an image browsed by a file input to database. I am browing the image using redactor plugin using this code

```
$('.editor').redactor({
    imageUpload:"/uploads"
});
```

Using this when i select or browse an image i am directly sending that image to server using meteor HTTP-methods

```
HTTP.methods({
    '/uploads': function(data) {
     console.log(data)
     Meteor.call("uploadImage",data)  
     return JSON.stringify({'Hello':"hello"});
    }
 });
```

Here when i am doing console.log data I am getting the 64bit binary code for the image. Now i want to save this data to the mongodb database.
I am using meteor-collection 2 for defining fields and their types. But i couldn't get which data type i have to use to store image to the mongo db.
I am trying to use mongodb gridfs to store the image. Tell me how can i store image in mongodb ? Thanx

Comment: Hey there, i am also trying to redactor editor, did fix you problem? I couldn't find any solution. How did you manage to call HTTP methods?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this package, it provides everything you need : https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS

I use it to store file in Mongo in different app.